# Setting Background image to GUI

Tags: python, image, tkinter, background, python-3.6

I made a GUI with few buttons and I want to change the gray background to an image.

my code looks like this:

```
from tkinter import *
from urlread import givenumbers # my function

""" Setting The Main GUI """

GUI = Tk()
GUI.title('Check GUI')
GUI.iconbitmap('test.ico')
GUI.geometry("400x400")

background_image=PhotoImage('pic.jpg')
background_label = Label(GUI, image=background_image)
background_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

""" Reading Images For Buttons """
A_Im      = PhotoImage(file='A.gif')


""" Creating Buttons """
# A Button
A_Button = Button(GUI, image=A_Im, command=givenumbers)
A_Button.grid(column=0, row=1)

GUI.mainloop()
```

The code runs without error but the background is still gray without any effect.

Comment: You need to call either the `pack()` or `grid()` layout managers for a widget to be displayed: i.e. `background_label.pack(<args>)`. You also need to call `GUI.mainloop()` at the very end for anything to appear.

Comment: I have edited the question, i added more lines of code that maybe make problems with grid. Thank you

Comment: That's a bit of an improvement, but what we really need is a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can reproduce (and help you fix) the problem. From the code you've added, the only thing I see is that you're mixing layout managers within the same container.

Comment: i reposted it as short as possible containing everything except the actual .ico and .gif files

Comment: you can use [Canvas](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm) to put image and widgets above this image.

Comment: standard `PhotoImage` supports only `GIF`. If you want to use other formats you have to use `PIL` module. http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm

Comment: @furas: I'm having no problems using `PhotoImage` with a .gif (in Python 3.6).

Comment: can someone give a full line of code showing what i need to right please? i dont care to change the format to .gif. PIL isnt working on windows 10 for me somewhy.

Comment: @martineau standard `PhotoImage` has no problem with `.gif` but doesn't work with `.png` and `.jpg` - OP uses `.jpg` as background with `Label`.

Comment: @ben see link to photoimage in my previous comment - there is example.

Comment: @furas: `PhotoImage` works with `.png` in python 3.6, but for `.jpg`, `PIL` is needed.

Comment: @j_4321 nice to know - I still use 3.5.

Comment: @furas I think I could already do it with 3.5

Comment: @j_4321 I will have to check it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the line `background_image=PhotoImage('pic.jpg')`. The PhotoImage class only supports GIF-files, which means that it cannot read the file you're specifying. You should try something like this:

```
#Python 2.7    
import Tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
window = tk.Tk()
image = Image.open('image.jpg')
photo_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
label = tk.Label(window, image = photo_image)
label.pack()

# Python 3
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
window = tk.Tk()
image = Image.open('image.jpg')
photo_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
label = tk.Label(window, image = photo_image)
label.pack()
```

The Image class from the PIL module supports a variety of formats, among which `jpeg` and `png`. You can install the PIL module by running `pip install pillow` in a command prompt or terminal.

If you want to put the widgets on top of the `Label`, you could indeed using `grid` to get them on top of each other, but using a `Canvas` would probably be easier. You can find more about the `Canvas` widget [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm).

Comment: hey thank you, i tried installing and i found its not supporting windows 10 somewhy

Comment: @ben: Nowadays most folks use [`pillow`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow), a fork of the Python Imaging Library instead of `PIL`. The former is still under active development and is supported.

Comment: @ben Did the command give you an error message? If you did not check the option "Add Python.exe to PATH" during installation, it indeed doesn't work. You could try navigating to your Python installation directory, holding SHIFT, right-click, then select "Open a command prompt here" and then type `python -m pip install pillow`.

Comment: the line with from PIL import Image is in grey color like not active. The PATH is set to the right place

Comment: @ben What do you mean? Are you using PyCharm or another IDE? The syntax highlighting can be different across IDEs.

Comment: Yes Pycharm mate.

Comment: @ben Personally I use PyCharm too, on Windows 7 as well as on Windows 8.1 and 10 virtual machines, and I had no problems at all getting it to work this way on Python 2.7. On Python 3, I know that on Linux (Debian-derivatives) you need to install `python3-pil.imagetk`, but as far as I know `ImageTk` should work with Windows directly through `pillow` on Python 3.

Comment: @RedFantom, When i try to add widgets it dont show them now (i guess its because the background is infront of them) is there a way to fix it? thank you mate.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done without pil also:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as ttk

""" Setting The Main GUI """

GUI = Tk()

F1=Frame(GUI)
F1=Frame(GUI,width=400,height=450)
F1.place(height=7000, width=4000, x=100, y=100)
F1.config()


F1.grid(columnspan=10,rowspan=10)

F1.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
F1.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)


photo=PhotoImage(file="C:\\Users\\HOME\\Desktop\\Eshita\\12th\\computer
\\python\\GUI\\math3.gif")
label = Label(GUI,image = photo)
label.image = photo # keep a reference!
label.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=20,rowspan=20)

b=ttk.Button(GUI,text="Start")
b.grid(row=8,column=8)

GUI.mainloop()
```